# After updating ubuntu 14.04 to ubuntu-proposed using software updater on jun 27th built-in notebook display keeps showing boot screen

Tags: multiple-monitors, gui

after updating ubuntu 14.04 using software updater to ubuntu-proposed automatic displays configuration stopped working correctly. My built-in notebook display keeps showing ubuntu boot screen(the one with ubuntu logo and 5dots as "progressbar"). Other display(s) are correctly switched to ubuntu login screen as expected. Same problem remains after login. I need to switch off built-in display and turn it back on using "Displays" settings to solve the problem. Do you have any idea if it is some configuration problem or is it a bug and I simply downgrade everything to trusty/trusty-updates?
My configuration is:

- Ubuntu 14.04LTS, all packages up to date with trusty-proposed repository
- Notebook LenovoT520
- 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
- 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119M [Quadro NVS 4200M] (rev a1)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-proposed` repo is for package updates that are yet to be verified to be safe and not introduce regressions. This looks like one of those regressions. You shouldn't be using package from this section (unless you're knowingly pulling in a package for testing).

Your best chance is to boot from a live CD, remove the `trusty-proposed` lines from `/etc/apt/sources.list`, and downgrade the packages to the standard repos, starting with the Linux kernel packages.

Comment: Thank you, saiarcot895, I fixed it already. Maybe I should report it as a bug in trusty-proposed to prevent it will be included in "production" updates later. What do you think?

Comment: You could, but it's expected that there are bugs in `trusty-proposed`. The other thing is that you installed all of the packages from that repo, so it could be that the combination of packages caused the bugs. Also, we don't know if it was the kernal packages that caused the bug or something else.

Comment: My worst nightmare is here. It came with standard update as well